# Why is my view being flagged as an XSS vulnerability?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, xss, brakeman

I have a `show` route that displays the contents of my article

**Controller:**

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

**View:**

```
...
<li class="content"><%= @article.content.html_safe %></li>
...
```

When running Brakeman, it flags the above as a potential Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability

```
Unescaped model attribute near line 34: Article.find(params[:article_id]).content
```

I'm trying to figure out what XSS really is and what makes this vulnerable? If someone injected some malicious text or input into the `params[:id]` field in the route (e.g. `/articles/BAD_INPUT`) then `Article.find()` would not find the article and raise an error

The only way the view renders is if a valid `Article` record is found, right? How else can the user manipulate this?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I should definitely protect agains the case when an Article is not found and an error is raised, but I figured that's more of a bad design rather than a security vulnerability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brakeman is warning because the code is taking information from the database and outputting it in a view without escaping it. By default, Brakeman treats values from the database as potentially dangerous. In this case, you probably know the article content is intended to be HTML and is safe to output without escaping it. If you wish to not warn about XSS with values from the database, you can use the `--ignore-model-output` option.

(The issue you linked in your answer is not really related. Brakeman is expected to warn about uses of `raw`/`html_safe` with potentially dangerous values.)

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, why are values from the DB inherently untrusted? I'd expect input like `params` that come straight from users and forms to be untrusted, but presumably more often than not the data that has made it into the DB has been validated and is now just being retrieved, right?

Comment: @user2490003: The reason is because the database could be storing raw user input. A great example is Stack Overflow - there will be `<script>` tags in the database because people post code to the site - it is impossible to validate it against malicious input. The way Stack Overflow (and most good systems) is to encode on _output_. It's a bit trickier though if you want users to enter safe HTML.

Comment: @SilverlightFox - Thanks so much, that makes sense. Validating HTML for malicious code does seem to be a tougher larger problem. Marking this answer as accepted, but one final question if any can spare an answer - was my approach that I detailed in my answer above (below?) correct? Or was it merely just a way to "fool" brakeman into not detecting the fact that I'm marking something from the DB as `html_safe` ?

Comment: @user2490003: You're not fooling it by doing it that way. By coding it in such a way you are making the statement "I am fully aware that this is raw HTML and I know what I'm doing", therefore brakeman knows to ignore it.

Comment: No, @user2490003 is correct. The code is "fooling" Brakeman because it does not (currently) know that `view_context.raw` is equivalent to `raw`. If it did, it would warn about it. `raw` and especially `html_safe` are often used without people knowing what they do.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the insight. And thanks Justin for your time in developing Brakeman!

Answer (score 2):

Ok found the answer after some digging.

It apparently has to do with `html_safe` and `raw` (which is just an alias for `html_safe`). The issue is specific to Brakeman and outlined [here](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/issues/516)

That thread says the issue is acknowledged and solved, but it still didn't work for me using the latest version.

I solved it as follows

**Controller:**

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article_content = view_context.raw(@article.content)
end
```

**View:**

```
...
<li class="content"><%= @article_content %></li>
...
```

Essentially we're marking the Article content as `html_safe` (using the alias `raw()`) beforehand so it doesn't cause an issue in the view.

Messier than I'd like, but it works

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing html on your model and you are on Rails 4.2++, you could consider using the `sanitize` helper ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)).

For example, you can allow specific tags (e.g. links):

```
<%= sanitize @article.content, tags: %w(a), attributes: %w(href) %>
```

The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) have a lot of good examples.

Here's [another write-up](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/07/the-new-html-sanitizer-in-rails-4-2/) if you want some more information.